# Truly unanswered questions

Tags: discussion

Clicking "unanswered" shows you questions w/o *ACCEPTED* (upvoted) answers, but 
has someone written a script/site that shows you questions w/ *NO* 
answers, upvoted or otherwise?

It seems easy to code using the API, so I'm guessing its been done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done without a script. Just [search for](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers:0) `answers:0`.

Comment: I'm guessing this works for many/all tags. Where can I see a full list and/or docs for the search engine?

Comment: @user3652:Search for nothing.

Comment: @user3652: In other words... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=

Comment: that's not using the API though?